# Neo4j community edition in read-only mode

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to make the config flag `dbms.read_only=true` working with Neo4j community edition (I know there are user roles in the enterprise, but I'm not wealthy enough for their expensive fees).

I've done this:

- Created a database as read/write, using Neo4j Desktop (v1.1.8) under Mac and 3.4.5 as database engine.
- Populated it with just a few nodes
- Stopped, set `dbms.read_only=true` and restarted

At the last step, the server logs shows the error: "UnsupportedOperationException: Can't create index writer in read only mode" and shuts down. So, is that option really (still) working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j Desktop is meant for usage with Enterprise Edition (you do get an individual license for usage for dev purposes only), not Community Edition.

I believe there's an issue with `dbms.read_only=true` and running via Neo4j Desktop, but there isn't any problem using the server deployment of Neo4j Community edition and using that setting.

My advice would be to download the community edition from Neo4j and use that directly rather than going through Neo4j Desktop.